# Bounded and open, cover

Tags: real-analysis

Hello is bounded definition has some relation with open and closed set?

Bounded should be closed?

I'm little bit confused with definition

Because open Sets definition is it should include all interior points

But it sounds like its closed(because all interior point is closed with boundary)

Why they call it as open set?

I need to clear with this definitions

Comment: bounded, open, closed can occur in all eight possible combinations

Comment: *Bounded* has virtually no connection with *boundary*. It is unfortunate that the first five letters are the same.

Comment: A bounded set is just one that can be contained in a ball of finite radius, or a set whose "diameter"--the maximal distance between any two points in the set- is itself finite.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Maybe not in general, but I'd say that for intervals in $\mathbb{R}$ the connection is quite clear.

Answer (score 3):

No, boundedness has nothing to do with being open or closed. In $\Bbb R$

- $[0,1]$ is bounded, closed, and not open;
- $(0,1)$ is bounded, open, and not closed;
- $[0,1)$ is bounded, not open, and not closed;
- $\varnothing$ is bounded, open, and closed;
- $\Bbb Z$ is unbounded, closed, and not open;
- $(0,\to)$ is unbounded, open, and not closed;
- $\left(\frac13,\frac23\right)\cup\Bbb Z$ is unbounded, not open, and not closed; and
- $\Bbb R$ is unbounded, open, and closed.

Thus, every combination of boundedness/unboundedness, closed/not closed, and open/not open is possible.